# fusedLocationProvider running on main thread, even if method is called from different runnable thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance, location

```
  autoSearch_button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        grant_permission();
        check_location_enableornot();
        lastButton_pressed = view.getId();
        ExampleRunnable exampleRunnable = new ExampleRunnable(20);
        Thread thread = new  Thread(exampleRunnable);
        thread.start();
        thread.join();
    });
 
  public class ExampleRunnable implements Runnable {
    private int kmRadius;
    private double lat =0 , longi =0 ;

    public ExampleRunnable(int i) {
        this.kmRadius = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        lastLocation();
    }  
    
    private void lastLocation(){
        Log.i(TAG, "lastLocation: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        
       fusedLocationProviderClient =  LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MainActivity.this);
       // for now being assume that i have declared     
      @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") Task<Location> locationTask = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        locationTask.addOnSuccessListener(location -> {
            if (location != null) {
                //We have a location
                Log.d(TAG, "run: last location" +  Thread.currentThread().getName()););
                this.lat = location.getLatitude();
                this.longi = location.getLongitude();
                print();
            } else  {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: Location was null... calling robust");
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + e.getLocalizedMessage() ));
      }
    }
   
    public synchronized void print(){
      Log.d(TAG, "print: " + Thread.currentThread.getName());
    }
 }
```

Output what i want in logcat

- lastlocation: thread4
- run: lastLocation thread4
- print: thread4

But what result i am getting -
lastlocation: thread4 //
run: lastLocation main //
print: main

I want to handle location and working over it in a particular thread

Answer (score 2):

> `locationTask.addOnSuccessListener`

This doesn't run the listener, it merely registers the block of code that follows with the `locationTask` object, and that object can do whatever it wants with it.

Evidently (and this is common with event handler systems like this), some thread ends up executing some event, and as a consequence of this, the listeners for that event are run right then and there, in that thread.

You have two solutions:

1. Cause whatever event ends up triggering the listener (your code doesn't help explain where that is; the thing that causes the object that variable `locationTask` is pointing at to enter the 'success' state, thus triggering your listener) to occur in the thread you want it to occur in, and not main.
2. Don't fire up a thread to register a success listener; fire up a thread within your success listener (so instead of `Log.d(TAG, "run: last location"...`, start a thread).

Sometimes, event handler systems are configurable and you can tell it to fire such events in other threads, but this is rare. If the library doesn't support it (and I doubt it does), you'd have to write wrapper methods or wrap the entire library to get this.